# Adding an aggregated column to a data frame using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to add an aggregated column to a data frame using dplyr. Here is an example of what I have in mind:

```
gender <- c("male", "female", "male")
age <- c(25, 30, 56)
weight <- c(160, 110, 220)
mydata <- data.frame(gender, age, weight)
```

I group the data frame **mydata** by gender before making an aggregated calculation to find the average weight by gender:

```
library(dplyr)
mydata <- group_by(mydata, gender)
mydata2 <- summarise(mydata, wt=mean(weight))
```

Is there any way of adding the column of average weight to the original data frame in the same step as above? In SQL, I would achieve this using the following line of code:

```
SELECT gender, age, weight, avg(weight) as avg_wt FROM mydata GROUP BY gender
```

I realize this is a very basic question, but I am new to R and I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Comment: Replace summarise with mutate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it is of interest, this can be accomplished in base R using the `ave` function:

```
mydata$avg_wt <- ave(mydata$weight, mydata$gender, FUN=mean)
```

The first argument is the variable to which the function will be applied, the second, the grouping variable, while the third is the function that will be applied by group.

```
 mydata
  gender age weight avg_wt
1   male  25    160    190
2 female  30    110    110
3   male  56    220    190
```

Note that the default value of the FUN argument is "mean", so it is possible to shorten the above code to

```
mydata$avg_wt <- ave(mydata$weight, mydata$gender)
```

I added this argument in the answer above as an indication that, despite its name, `ave` is capable of calculating group other statistics (including user-written functions).

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks. You are right. I like to add it into the answer as a reminder that, despite its name, that you can use it to calculate other functions. I'll make a note of this in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Use `mutate` instead of `summarise`:

```
mydata %>% group_by(gender) %>% mutate(wt = mean(weight))


#Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
#Groups: gender [2]
#
#  gender   age weight    wt
#  (fctr) (dbl)  (dbl) (dbl)
#1   male    25    160   190
#2 female    30    110   110
#3   male    56    220   190
```